# Having issues fixing editor showing random letters in line and in file tree explorer

Tags: terminal, neovim, neovim-plugin

I am working on my Neovim setup and have decided to use NVChad to bootstrap alot of the initial setup for me. The issue I am facing is with my editor and my file tree showing random letters on initial load but then go away once passed over through navigation.

Below is an exmaple of the issue I am facing.

[image]

As you can see in line 3, it shows 'ffro dotenv ..." but when I navigate to that line and go to insert mode it goes away completely. You can also see an exmaple of this happening in the file tree to the left of line 3. I have installed the plugins recommended to view the icons and even tried removing icons altogether but still no luck. Looking for someone to point me in the right direction of which plugin could be causing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to fix this by just going with the default configuration for the nvim tree plugin.